# Get music playlist artwork src url in social engine

Tags: php, socialengine

I am using social engine 4.2 with the music module and I need to echo src url for a playlist photo. The code that prints the html for the playlist artwork in the music modules is

`<?php echo $this->itemPhoto($playlist, null, $playlist->getTitle(),array('width' =>        '200px', 'height' => '200px')) ?>`

can anyone point me in the right direction?

best,